# How can I amend this M query to make PowerBI get all the pages concurrently from a rest API?

Tags: rest, pagination, powerbi, response-headers

This is my current code. It of course only returns the first page:

```
let
 url = "https://id.myapi.ac.uk/connect/token",
 GetJson = Web.Contents(url,
     [
         Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"],
         Content = Text.ToBinary("client_id=mechamp&client_secret=notthislol&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=myapi") 
     ]
 ),
 FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
 // Gets token from the Json response
 AccessToken = FormatAsJson[access_token],
 AccessTokenHeader = "bearer " & AccessToken,
 // Uses the GET search method using the bearer token from the previous POST oauth2/token method
 GetJsonQuery = Web.Contents("https://data.api.myapi.ac.uk/activities?recordState=0&pageSize=100",
     [
         Headers = [#"Authorization"=AccessTokenHeader,
                    #"api-version"="2",
                    #"Accept"="application/json"]
     ]
 ),
 FormatAsJsonQuery = Json.Document(GetJsonQuery),
Name"})
in
    FormatAsJsonQuery
```

I previously implemented this in Excel, using a curl request wrapped in a batch file created by VBA. Omitting the parts that already work in M query the batch file looked like this:

```
rem ommiting getting the token and setting it as %token%
set pagenum=1
set pagesize=100

curl "{https://data.api.myapi.ac.uk/activities?&page=%pagenum%&pageSize=1&recordstate=0}" -G  --header "api-version: 2" --header "Authorization: Bearer %token%" --header "Accept: application/json" --trace-ascii %userprofile%\api\totalpages.txt

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "totalCount" %userprofile%\api\totalpages.txt') do set "totalrecords=%%a"  
set totalrecords=%totalrecords:,"t=%
set totalrecords=%totalrecords:0000: X-Pagination: {"currentPage":1,"pageSize":1otalCount":=%
rem del %userprofile%\api\totalpages.txt
set /a totalpages = %totalrecords%/%pagesize%
set /a totalpages = %totalpages%+1

start "" /min curl "{https://data.api.heat.ac.uk/activities?&page=%pagenum%&pageSize=%pagesize%&recordstate=0&sort=-activityStartDate}" -G --data-urlencode "fields=%fields%" --header "api-version: 2" --header "Authorization: Bearer %token%" --header "Accept: application/xml" --output %userprofile%\api\file%pagenum%.txt

:loop
set /A pagenum=pagenum+1
start "" /min curl "{https://data.api.heat.ac.uk/activities?&page=%pagenum%&pageSize=%pagesize%&recordstate=0&sort=-activityStartDate}" -G --data-urlencode "fields=%fields%" --header "api-version: 2" --header "Authorization: Bearer %token%" --header "Accept: application/xml" --output %userprofile%\api\file%pagenum%.txt
if %pagenum% LSS %totalpages% (goto :loop)

rem omitting lines that copy all the destination files into one and format into into a valid single json
exit
```

You can see it first makes a request and dumps the raw output into a file, including the headers which tell me how many records there are, which I can then use to work out how many pages there are. I googled how to get the headers in PowerBI, but in their unwisdom it seems that Microsoft have decided nobody needs them and would do bad things with them.

How can I find out how many pages there are and request them all at once?

*Edit: the below are attempts to find out how many pages there are. The alternative would be to just keep requesting the next page until the server returns 404, that's fine if it works concurrently. In other words if this can work without seeing the response headers, that's good enough for me. I'm new to power bi so if you can point me in the direction of a script which does that, that would be great.*

*This blog post is widely cited as demonstrating that approach, but unfortunately is no longer available: https://www.mattmasson.com/2014/11/iterating-over-an-unknown-number-of-pages-in-power-query/ Internet archive also doesn't contain this*.

Things that I couldn't make work:
https://medium.com/@marktiedemann/how-to-do-pagination-in-power-query-430460c17c78
"@odata.count" was not found was the error I received, apparently not supported by this API.

There was a reference to something called WebMethod.Head, which sounds interesting, but no documentation is provided on how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/webmethod-head

I tried to recreate this exact script which claims to receive the response headers, but the syntax didn't work
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Retrieve-API-response-headers/td-p/423704?lightbox-message-images-641107=151369i21A62C85FABC9F9C

[image]

Apparent for some apis it's as simple as

```
= try GetJsonQuery[next_page_url] otherwise null
```

And for me it's null!

Odata.Feed tells me that there is no Odata at this endpoint.

```
GetJsonQuery = OData.Feed("https://data.myapi.ac.uk/activities?recordState=0&pageSize=100",
 [
     #"Authorization"="bearer " & "AccessToken",
                #"api-version"="2",
                #"Accept"="application/json"




], [IncludeMetadataAnnotations="*"]  )  in
    GetJsonQuery
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please anybody?!

Comment: were you able to solve that? I am also trying to obtain the XSRF-TOKEN or the cookies.

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately not. I was getting towards a brute-force solution for requesting more pages, but I had to give up as, incredibly, PowerBI isn't capable of requesting more than one page with a Bearer token form of authentication. You have to set the credentials to 'anonymous' and then write the creds manually in the request - that works fine for the 1st page but then it checks if 'anonymous' can access the endpoint - which of course it can't without the credentials

Comment: I wrote a batch script instead which downloads everything to a local file and then opens the PowerBI file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I couldn't solve it either, better to change the authentication endpoint, send some parameter so that it knows that the request goes from powerbi, if it goes from powerbi then just get a token and then concatenate it in the authorization header.